# Problems with eventHandler arguments using geous.js lib

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-handling, dom-events

I'm having problems to retrieve the argument passed to my eventHandler.

I'm using [geous](https://github.com/rjz/geous.js/) to put a map inside and activeadmin interface. The solution is working on the show page but I didn't get things working on the index page. The idea is to attach the handler to the dragend event on a marker with my model geographic coordinates.

What I do:

```
map.locations.add($fields.geousable('getLocation'), { draggable: true, on: { dragend: setFieldsLocation }});
```

and setFieldsLocation is defined below:

```
  function setFieldsLocation (event) {
      alert(setFieldsLocation.caller);
       console.log(event);
      $('.geousable').find("input")[0].value = event.data.lat;
      $('.geousable').find("input")[1].value = event.data.lng;
  };
```

So the first line bind the handler (for dragend) and a method inside the geous lib code attachs it and calls it when the event is fired, here is the snippet:

```
var _onAdd = function (locationMarker, opts) {
            // not relevant code

            if (options.on) {
                for (event in options.on) {

                    eventHandler = function() {
                        var handler = options.on[event],
                            location = locationMarker.location;

                        return function() {
                            handler.call(location);
                        }
                    }();

                    google.maps.event.addListener(locationMarker.marker, event, eventHandler);
                }
            }
        };
```

Debugger shows the location correct location variable when the handler is called, but I can't get the location variable inside my "setFieldsLocation" function. I tried a lot of things. I changed the header of the javascript function, I used event, e, arguments and this kind of things:

```
console.log("arguments.callee.caller.name = " +
         arguments.callee.caller.name);
     console.log("arguments.callee.caller.toString() = " +
         arguments.callee.caller.toString());
```

But no luck.

Ideas with an explanation of what is occurring here will be very appreciated.

Comment: the first argument passed to `call` is the thisArgument, use the desired argument as 2nd argument

Comment: I could solve it using var location = this; inside the method. I don't understand what you say about the 2nd one.

Comment: documentation:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call  the first argument passed to `call` is the object that will be available via `this` inside the called function. When you pass only 1 argument to `call` the called function(`handler` in your example) doesn't receive any arguments.

Comment: Excelent. I can accept this as an answer if you want to. Best.